# Cloud Run downloading a file from GCS is insanely slow

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a Go cloud run app and when it starts, it downloads a 512mb file from GCS (it needs this for the program). Locally on my nothin-special home connection this works fine and it downloads in a few seconds, but when I deploy this to cloud run it downloads like a snail. I had to increase timeouts and log a progress counter in just to make sure it was doing something (it was). It might be downloading at about 30Kb/s which is not gonna work.

The cloud run instance and GCS regional bucket are both in us-east4. It doesn't seem like there are any knobs I can play with to get this to work and I don't see this issue/constraint documented.

Anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

Here is the code doing the downloading, along with copious logging because I couldn't tell if it was doing anything at first:

```
func LoadFilter() error {
    fmt.Println("loading filter")
    ctx := context.Background()
    storageClient, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer storageClient.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Minute*60)
    defer cancel()

    obj := storageClient.Bucket("my_slow_bucket").Object("filter_export")
    rc, err := obj.NewReader(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rc.Close()

    attrs, err := obj.Attrs(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    progressR := &ioprogress.Reader{
        Reader: rc,
        Size:   attrs.Size,
        DrawFunc: func(p int64, t int64) error {
            fmt.Printf("%.2f\n", float64(p)/float64(t)*100)
            return nil
        },
    }

    fmt.Println("reading filter...")
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(progressR)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("decoding filter...")
    filter, err := cuckoo.Decode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("filter decoded")

    cf = filter

    fmt.Println("initailized the filter successfully!")

    return nil
}
```

Comment: What is your measurement of "insanely slow"?  Do you have code with benchmarks to share?

Comment: All I am doing in the code is downloading a 512mb file to load into memory. Running the code locally at home it downloads the file at roughly 50MB/s. When deployed to cloud run, it downloads at 62 Kb/s. The cloud run instance was in the same region as the bucket, and has 1cpu and 2G memory. I'd expect at least several MB/sec from it.

Comment: I tried also tried a multi-region bucket, and tried deploying the service to us-east1 rather than us-east4 but the throughput on the download was the same.

Comment: Does this code run while there is an active request? Cloud Run throttles CPU when there is no active request.

Comment: That sounds very likely to be the issue! When I was testing this in a dev environment, I had very little traffic if any.  Decoding the bloom filter took forever too, which seemed to point at a CPU constraint as well but was not download speed related like I thought. When I rolled it to an env with more traffic the problem pretty much went away.

I suppose I could include the binary of the filter in the built container but that would mean rebuilding and deploying a new container version every day. Good to know about this CPU constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed what @wlhee said is perfectly true. if you have any activities that run outside or request pipeline, these activities will not have access to the full CPU provided to your instances. As the documentation says:

> When an application running on Cloud Run finishes handling a request,
> the container instance's access to CPU will be disabled or severely
> limited. Therefore, you should not start background threads or
> routines that run outside the scope of the request handlers.
>
> Running background threads can result in unexpected behavior because
> any subsequent request to the same container instance resumes any
> suspended background activity.

I suggest that you run this download activity from Cloud Storage upon a request to your services by hitting some startup endpoint in your app, finish the download then return a response to indicate a request ends.

Please, check this documentation for [tips on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general)

Comment: Thank you. That's a great suggestion, but are there any startup endpoints that I can count on being hit on each instance? If my app scales beyond one instance, it doesn't seem like there is any way to ensure that they will all have the endpoint called (If I am sending it). This app needs every instance to have the file downloaded.

Comment: I suppose I could initiate it on _any_ request at the expense of the that poor user's request latency.

It seems like the CPU becomes unconstrained and background processing is fast enough when there are requests flowing to the instance. In other words, CPU is scaled up when the control plane or LB detects traffic, and is not constrained to the scope of the request. Is that true?  I can appreciate the simplicity of stating that work should not be done outside the request path though.  :-)